# Prompt user to select a directory with a bash script and read result

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I want to be read a dir with a bash script (actually I am using zsh).

I want to list the current folders in the same dir and display it to the user asking them to enter a number to select the correct folder.

```
Please select a Folder eg, 1,2,3.
1. Folder Name 1 (this should the actual name of the folder in the dir
2. Folder 2
3. Folder 3.
```

I would like to also be able to convert the input eg 1. Back to the actual folder name so I can

```
cd ./$foldername/
```

Thanks for you help. 
Cheers, John.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unless your formatting requirements are very strict, you can probably just use *bash*’s [`select` construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-select-56).

The following code will present a menu of all the directories in the current directory and then chdir to the selected one:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Please select folder:\n"
select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
cd "$d" && pwd
```

Comment: WONDERFULL. TESTED AND WORKS LIKE A CHARM. THANKS!
That worked just the way I wanted it to.
Cheers, John.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(*/)

read -p "$(
        f=0
        for dirname in "${dirs[@]}" ; do
                echo "$((++f)): $dirname"
        done

        echo -ne 'Please select a directory > '
)" selection

selected_dir="${dirs[$((selection-1))]}"

echo "You selected '$selected_dir'"
```

Comment: Thanks works for me. If want use directories from variables: `dirs=( "$dir"/"$prd"/* );` or directories that start with some name `dirs=( "$dir"/"$prd"/["$src"]* );`

Answer (score 3):

Saw this snippet @ some stack link dunno exactly..though might be useful

```
 #! /bin/bash

# customize with your own.
options=(backup_*/)

menu() {
    clear
    echo "Avaliable options:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
}

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] && (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) || {
        msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue
    }
    ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
    [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="[+]"
done

printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
for i in ${!options[@]}; do 
    [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
done
echo "$msg"
```