# Processing the list of a select construct in bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script in which the user has to choose one option from a list. The list of options is actually the list of the basenames (with no path and no extension) of the files in a directory, plus the additional requirement that symbolic links should be excluded.

I loved the one liner posted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200252/prompt-user-to-select-a-directory-with-a-bash-script-and-read-result) which is originally meant for choosing subdirectories:

```
printf "Please select folder:\n"
select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
cd "$d" && pwd
```

I know how to get the `basename` of a file, and how to check if a file is not a symbolic link, but that's file by file. However, the `select` construct manages a list of files. Can I plug somehow the `basename` command and the `! -L` check on the fly to all the elements in the `select` construct, thus filtering and processing the list before it arrives to `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your filenames have no embedded newlines, which is rarely a concern):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Collect the sorted names of all regular files in the current directory
# in array ${files[@]}.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d/ -f2 | sort)
# Bash 4.x would allow the simpler:
# readarray -t files < ...

select f in "${files[@]}"; do
  [[ -n "$f" ]] && break # Valid selection made, exit the menu.
  echo ">>> Invalid Selection" >&2
done

# "$f" contains the selected file.
```

Note that depending on your platform and `find` implementation, this could be streamlined.

`-type f` matches only regular files and automatically excludes symlinks.

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to be as backwards compatible as possible, and not rely on Bash 4.x. In fact, if the solution was even compatible with the Bourne shell, I'd prefer it.

Comment: @cesss, aside: Do you *really* mean Bourne (the 1970s-era shell that allows `^` to be used as a pipe character), or do you mean POSIX sh (the early-90s standard of which bash, ksh, dash, etc. are superset implementations)?

Comment: @cesss: I've made the solution Bash 3.x compatible. If you want a truly portable solution, please don't tag your question `bash`. Note that the `select` command is not part of the POSIX shell spec., and neither are array variables.

Comment: Yes, @mkelement0 , you are very right that I tagged this as bash. I'm fine with bash, and, in fact, if this was to be Bourne-compatible, the `select` construct couldn't be used.

Comment: However, I'm getting this error (running OSX): `syntax error near unexpected token '<' `  (this is in the IFS line)

Comment: @cesss, that sounds like you're not running bash. `read ... < <(...)` should work perfectly well on the bash 3.2 release OS X ships with, when not running in portability mode.

Comment: @cess: To add to Charles' comment: perhaps you're invoking your script with `sh` rather than `bash` - even though `sh` _is_ `bash` on macOS, it runs in POSIX compatibility _when invoked as `sh`_, in which case process substitutions (`<(...)`)  are not recognized. Change your shebang line to use `bash`, or invoke your script explicitly with `bash`.

Comment: True! The script had indeed the correct `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but however I was calling it from another script with `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. Changing both files to `bash` makes it work beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

A suboptimal approach that avoids bashisms (despite your question explicitly requesting a bash solution), and moreover avoids depending on any tools not built into the shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
set --                        ## clear our argument list to reuse it

printf "Please select folder:\n"
for d in */; do               ## iterate only over directories
  [ -L "${d}%/" ] && continue ## skip to next item if we have a link
  d=${d%/}; d=${d##*/}        ## alternative to basename using only parameter expansion
  set -- "$@" "$d"            ## append our result to "$@"
done
select d in "$@"; do          ## ...and then expand "$@" to select over
  cd "$d" && pwd
done
```

---

Notably:

- `"$@"` is the only array guaranteed to be available in baseline POSIX sh. Note that each stack frame provides a different argument list, so by encapsulating this code inside a function you can avoid overwriting the global `"$@"`.
- If we were writing this for bash, we could do array appends as an O(1) operation via `array+=( "$value" )`, rather than the O(n) `set -- "$@" "$value"` (which needs to expand the current list, and thus grows slower with the existing argument list lengnh).

Comment: But isn't avoiding Bashisms a futile exercise in this case, given that the `select` statement is not part of the POSIX shell spec?

Comment: @mklement0, *shrug*. The spec explicitly makes provisions for `select`, even though it doesn't require it. There certainly are non-bash shells (going back at least to early ksh) that support it.

Comment: Yes, `ksh` and `zsh` also support `select`, but `dash` doesn't, for instance. What I found in the [spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) is: "The following words may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations (when none of the characters are quoted), causing unspecified results: `[[`, `]]`, `function`, `select`"

Comment: Charles, I'd wish I could accept both answers. In fact, in this moment I'm not sure if I'm going to follow mkelement0 answer or yours. However, mkelement0 answered it correctly, under the original premise (tagged bash), so I check it as accepted answer although I appreciate a lot your alternative approach. I'll study both.

Comment: @Charles, in your answer you state that your proposal is slower.  Do you think additional statements make it slower despite not having to execute "find", "cut" and "sort"?  Or is your comment a reference to the example in the question?

Comment: @Fred, ...you're right; I communicated badly here. `set -- "$@" "$foo"` is much slower than `array+=( "$arg" )` (the latter being O(1), the former being O(n) with the existing size of the list)... but that's a relative scale; by avoiding external commands, though, you're right that this is still faster overall. What I meant to indicate was that we were passing up chances to optimize in favor of portability, rather than that we were slower overall, but I didn't really make that point.

Comment: @Fred, ...hopefully the current revision is better?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I think the meaning of your comment is clearer now.